# How to validate before passing a wrong country code to google-libphonenumber?

Tags: javascript, iso, libphonenumber

I am using the library `google-libphonenumber` and noticing that if a non viable option is passed to `phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput('202-341-2345', 'ZZ')` it automatically throws and errors and breaks the site.

What I want to do is either allow some way of saying if this piece of code did not work then alert and error or I need a way to validate the input with all the i18n iso codes before.

Comment: try/catch perhaps? or validate the input before calling the function

Comment: Is there a good library for validating i18n iso codes?

Comment: I think good browsers (and some bad ones) don't need a library - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl - hmmm, maybe not, my google fu failed

Comment: For the requirement you mentioned, you should only need to validate if a string is a valid phone number or not, which can be done simply by javascript regex. What is he exact requirement for " validate the input with all the i18n iso codes before." ? What exactly and Why do you want to do this iso code validation.

Comment: `you should only need to validate if a string is a valid phone number or not, which can be done simply by javascript regex` - really? so all number formats from around the world can be validated *simply* by using regex? Do tell

Comment: I am using the library stated above so I dont need to do any validation on the phone number, that is what the library is for. However if I pass an invalid iso code then the variable will break and the application will as well. I am messing with try and catch to alert an error instead of crashing the app.

Comment: I found a way around this, I will put answer below.

Comment: I have found javascript libraries, but they're all node-centric. How good are you at making node modules run in a browser?

Comment: ahh, you "found" try/catch :p

Comment: Regex can filter out i18n codes and return you true/false. e.g /^[0-9-_]*$/.test('正则表达式可以做任何事情') would return false - unless it is a valid phone number. I would like to know what I am missing here - all phone numbers around the world have only digits in them 0-9 + a few spacer characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the exact problem that I was trying to solve was to not crash the application because an invalid country calling code or iso code was passed in. If for example I passed zz into the second argument of:

`phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput('202-341-2345', 'ZZ')`

This was causing my whole application to crash and show the error. While all I wanted to do is only alert the error and not let the user continue with the process. So there was two ways to do this. Either validate the country calling code or iso code, or do a try catch block to alert an error if the variable did not work.

I took the try catch block since this is a way I can show the error directly which tells the user their iso code is wrong anyway. So no need for validating either since it is already done.

Here is the code:

```
  let userNumber = null;

    try {
      userNumber = phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput(
        this.state.phoneNumber,
        this.state.isoCode.toUpperCase()
      );
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
      return;
    }

    if (userNumber) {
      alert(phoneUtil.isValidNumber(userNumber));
      alert(phoneUtil.format(userNumber, PNF.E164));
      return;
    }
```